# Why do I get illegal character U+FFFDerror when using import (in JS)?

Tags: javascript, module

When I use import and export in my program, I find the error illegal character U+FFFDerror, does anyone know why?

I have two js files named main.js and modal.js and I export the gamePoint variable from the modal.js file to the main.js file.

I export variable like this in modal.js

```
const usernames = document.querySelectorAll('.get-username-modal input[type="text"]');
const savePlayerUsernameBtn = document.querySelector('.save-username');
const modal = document.querySelector('.get-username-modal');
//exported variable
export const gamePoint = document.querySelector('#limitPoint');
```

and import the variable in main.js like this

```
import gamePoint from "./modal.js";
```

and i get Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character U+FFFD in firefox

Comment: It means the body of the response from the server for the module (e.g., the module's code) contained the character [U+FFFD](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=FFFD), the "replacement character". The code you've posted to the question doesn't have that character in it, but it's in the response, and it's invalid (except inside strings and template literals) in JavaScript code. Look at the response in the Network tab. It *could* be a text encoding issue, but that's not the usual presentation of a text encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was missing Content-Encoding header in http response providing that js, the file was compressed with brotly.